# Discrepancy in Converting Date to TimeStamp in java

Tags: java, date, timestamp

I have a Date Object in following:

```
Date date=new Date("Mon, 05 May 2014 12:31:12 +0000")
```

I want to get Timestamp of date Object then :

```
date.getTime()

1399293072000
```

but this value not correct , correct value in following :

```
1399276872000 
//*** for get timestamp use of http://www.epochconverter.com ***\\
```

why ?

Comment: `1399293072000` is `Mon May 05 12:31:12 2014 +0000`, `1399276872000` is `Mon May 05 08:01:12 2014 +0000`. So the result *is* correct. Check your timezones.

Comment: Don't use deprecated methods, there's a reason why they've been depreciated...

Comment: Use this Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date.getTime());

Comment: @MadProgrammer getTime() method is not deprecated check once!!!

Comment: @Naveen `Date date=new Date("Mon, 05 May 2014 12:31:12 +0000")` is

Comment: @MadProgrammer fine!!!!

Comment: how to resolve this problem be always get value correct and same ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first, from the [JavaDoc for `Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29)

```
Date(String s)
Deprecated. 
As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by DateFormat.parse(String s).
```

So the constructor you are using has been deprecated since **1997**!

Next, onto the [JavaDoc for `Date.parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) which the construtor uses:

> It accepts many syntaxes; in particular, it recognizes the IETF
>   standard date syntax: "Sat, 12 Aug 1995 13:30:00 GMT". It also
>   understands the continental U.S. time-zone abbreviations, but for
>   general use, a time-zone offset should be used: "Sat, 12 Aug 1995
>   13:30:00 GMT+0430" (4 hours, 30 minutes west of the Greenwich
>   meridian). **If no time zone is specified, the local time zone is
>   assumed**. GMT and UTC are considered equivalent.

Empathsis mine.

So, what timezone are you in? Presumably not UTC.

Comment: I agree that this is related to the timezone that is used.

Comment: my timezone set to GMT with   TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

Comment: how to convert timezone of GMT+4.5 to GMT in java ?

Comment: @user986566 I would begin by using the [correct approach to parsing date strings](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/), then you can fairly easily use [`SimpleDateFomat.setTimeZone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone)). You can also use one of the default formats from [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should specify local time zone while constructing Date object

```
Example:
Date date=new Date("Mon, 05 May 2014 12:31:12 GMT+0530");
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Mon, 05 May 2014 12:31:12 +0000 at http://www.epochconverter.com I get 1399285872000 which is different from your timestamp.

Or you're passing different values, or there's a bug somewhere or

The Unix epoch (or Unix time or POSIX time or Unix timestamp) is the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 (midnight UTC/GMT), not counting leap seconds (in ISO 8601: 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z).

where the javadoc for java.util.Date.getTime() doesn't mention leap seconds.

Comment: A bug somewhere?! That's your explanation? Surely that can be the (unhelpful) answer to any question on SO?